# Pyspark take, collect and first return different value

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, numpy-ndarray

I run a Pyspark script that performs a `map` operation on a RDD. The result of such a `map` is a new RDD containing tuples, i.e. there is one tuple for each partition in the original RDD (there are 10 partitions). Each tuple contains two Numpy ndarray's and the partition ID.

The problem is `take(10)` and `collect()` return different values! Even, if a perform `first()` on the resulting RDD, the tuple is totally different from the first tuple returned by `take` or `collect`.

`take(10)` result is:

```
[(array([[ 0.19138815, -0.26613894,  0.0148395 , ..., -0.6887879 ,
         0.01775263,  0.29900053],
       [ 0.46834013, -0.41492677, -0.3986189 , ..., -0.09638319,
        -0.27234066,  0.41824088],
       [ 0.2235235 , -0.27003226,  0.05322047, ..., -0.3045229 ,
        -0.30364496,  0.21981548],
       ...,
       [ 0.40709212, -0.49947056,  0.36821032, ..., -0.27359277,
        -0.1552616 , -0.10506155],
       [ 0.42315334, -0.6249347 , -0.38093382, ..., -0.52247494,
         0.12167282,  0.53337336],
       [-0.12733063, -0.27234274, -0.05421005, ...,  0.3884521 ,
         0.19977048,  0.11347781]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.04737013, -0.13501787, -0.04363494, ..., -0.53189725,
        -0.1747366 ,  0.09700331],
       [ 0.59339726, -0.622871  , -0.7482438 , ...,  0.01563211,
        -0.24306081,  0.5259429 ],
       [ 0.199726  , -0.29667157,  0.03788655, ..., -0.72914207,
        -0.61997485,  0.4880442 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.10908518,  0.15787347,  0.13822514, ..., -0.015803  ,
        -0.05935803,  0.11415796],
       [ 0.02415699,  0.21212797, -0.01504083, ..., -0.0880443 ,
         0.03949256, -0.17959005],
       [-0.08058456, -0.00894655, -0.10706384, ...,  0.00954069,
        -0.18720922, -0.05665499]], dtype=float32), 0), (array([[ 0.53325355, -0.0129254 ,  0.10924862, ...,  0.2797827 ,
         0.44130138, -0.29074535],
       [ 0.29487053,  0.20387554,  0.00834447, ...,  0.3034479 ,
        -0.34347925,  0.48914096],
       [-0.36053488,  0.2551153 ,  0.23102154, ..., -0.08557958,
         0.2305064 , -0.11637823],
       ...,
       [ 0.50112355, -0.5487336 ,  0.1381122 , ..., -0.17219128,
         0.5784589 , -0.39060545],
       [ 0.47822553, -0.21500733, -0.02590418, ...,  0.45222896,
        -0.29980502, -0.4379743 ],
       [-0.27317327,  0.47888   ,  0.13328783, ...,  0.45453754,
        -0.03382564,  0.28364402]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.45505902,  0.20775506,  0.38936007, ...,  0.31039652,
         0.0612184 , -0.34329525],
       [ 0.44160137,  0.45554656,  0.24406506, ...,  0.20645882,
        -0.55068386,  0.61949503],
       [-0.9611948 ,  0.48338398,  0.8936671 , ..., -0.07192033,
        -0.04691654, -0.0583482 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.27866694,  0.11791337,  0.00603435, ..., -0.0984261 ,
         0.05514587, -0.16367936],
       [ 0.24686542, -0.01605012,  0.15803055, ...,  0.14647359,
         0.00465332, -0.21551773],
       [ 0.01786835,  0.08164094,  0.0458132 , ...,  0.09466646,
        -0.07061186,  0.04650302]], dtype=float32), 1), (array([[-0.30373037,  0.4013883 ,  0.5544747 , ..., -0.24839583,
        -0.434404  , -0.5419062 ],
       [ 0.3205092 , -0.21219605,  0.23547144, ..., -0.4373149 ,
         0.30616343, -0.45202586],
       [-0.25409338, -0.14463192,  0.30881113, ..., -0.29998812,
        -0.24947752, -0.18218543],
       ...,
       [-0.33871105,  0.20521186,  0.38351473, ...,  0.33596635,
         0.370852  , -0.46504658],
       [-0.23807049,  0.1317612 ,  0.07848132, ..., -0.32858378,
        -0.541284  , -0.4595052 ],
       [-0.17040105,  0.48929718, -0.39259502, ..., -0.15026243,
        -0.19829535,  0.18581793]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.5295805 ,  0.64539313,  0.47219488, ..., -0.4475045 ,
        -0.31032106, -0.60634965],
       [ 0.28920087, -0.2322041 ,  0.313627  , ..., -0.71224356,
         0.1539378 , -0.39970958],
       [-0.39529595, -0.50494266,  0.61120296, ..., -0.94842255,
        -0.7700451 ,  0.03852249],
       ...,
       [ 0.082367  , -0.09744105,  0.00574634, ...,  0.04329732,
         0.08105459, -0.20032766],
       [ 0.04620253,  0.18625231, -0.04047911, ..., -0.1547844 ,
        -0.01560262,  0.00372486],
       [ 0.0602592 ,  0.078048  ,  0.04372916, ..., -0.10393928,
        -0.27185628, -0.05753115]], dtype=float32), 2), (array([[-0.10130739, -0.5432671 ,  0.14230369, ..., -0.20037425,
        -0.50981474, -0.39152429],
       [-0.10439714, -0.19250502, -0.12469167, ...,  0.50656915,
         0.41846293, -0.12511848],
       [-0.12075678,  0.13746399, -0.10762265, ..., -0.33095708,
         0.38831544, -0.3573719 ],
       ...,
       [-0.33046186,  0.1675668 , -0.22495636, ...,  0.39853546,
        -0.21838626, -0.44713587],
       [ 0.1753454 , -0.16229314,  0.24015644, ..., -0.09867255,
        -0.6676028 , -0.03644819],
       [ 0.33300576, -0.28793842,  0.45033735, ...,  0.26602328,
         0.18528135, -0.37736982]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.4201235 , -0.42547926,  0.3823224 , ..., -0.14358595,
        -0.33159116, -0.47784004],
       [-0.29869375, -0.31769726,  0.00777127, ...,  0.5764582 ,
         0.160321  , -0.14145109],
       [ 0.08045941,  0.31604633, -0.22956751, ..., -0.551948  ,
         0.8479948 , -1.065378  ],
       ...,
       [ 0.02872542, -0.23239408,  0.10584452, ..., -0.19653268,
         0.01299276,  0.01154038],
       [-0.11145593, -0.04056952,  0.17250092, ...,  0.11815882,
        -0.09970374, -0.14516412],
       [ 0.03227303,  0.08426446, -0.04518193, ..., -0.04804583,
         0.11866879,  0.07962584]], dtype=float32), 3), (array([[-0.3442908 , -0.47924808, -0.17909145, ...,  0.57778424,
        -0.20964314, -0.38468337],
       [-0.1493048 ,  0.22245084, -0.19882523, ...,  0.38685095,
        -0.5174358 , -0.4666229 ],
       [-0.36909524, -0.32142702, -0.183554  , ...,  0.16354944,
        -0.31103647, -0.12249314],
       ...,
       [-0.45103338, -0.04599327,  0.3811725 , ..., -0.28528866,
        -0.47804165, -0.08458076],
       [ 0.2814856 , -0.07282971, -0.6203528 , ...,  0.1307708 ,
         0.01159024, -0.28599057],
       [-0.20529339,  0.39615756, -0.12310734, ...,  0.21978702,
         0.09362441,  0.282171  ]], dtype=float32), array([[-3.9894256e-01, -2.3258871e-01, -3.5374862e-01, ...,
         5.5857885e-01,  1.3151944e-02, -3.4470174e-01],
       [ 3.7879427e-03,  2.3241083e-01, -1.8348652e-01, ...,
         2.8142187e-01, -5.6694925e-01, -7.0757174e-01],
       [-1.0855644e+00, -1.0010500e+00, -5.0151312e-01, ...,
         1.0360012e+00, -8.4597129e-01,  3.6014456e-01],
       ...,
       [ 9.6085869e-02,  4.7818022e-03,  9.2197888e-02, ...,
         5.7999889e-04, -4.3681998e-02, -1.0792557e-01],
       [-2.1461031e-01, -7.9450890e-02, -3.6970940e-03, ...,
         1.2008668e-01,  8.1481531e-02, -7.4978117e-03],
       [ 2.2965204e-02, -7.5380646e-02, -1.5798187e-01, ...,
         2.3251076e-01,  2.0147276e-01, -5.9070695e-02]], dtype=float32), 4), (array([[ 0.34773657,  0.1271629 ,  0.35084245, ..., -0.4163662 ,
        -0.2032509 ,  0.16763268],
       [ 0.25300634, -0.24963312,  0.03022493, ..., -0.48368084,
        -0.5438243 , -0.2523892 ],
       [ 0.08074404,  0.34778172, -0.19389851, ...,  0.00394286,
        -0.03249731,  0.21850894],
       ...,
       [-0.28799132,  0.46877176,  0.13380927, ...,  0.21133232,
        -0.20794198,  0.04732013],
       [ 0.533321  ,  0.08838256,  0.52776694, ..., -0.3776623 ,
         0.3234356 ,  0.49971387],
       [ 0.01111342,  0.2225688 ,  0.5407952 , ..., -0.5621694 ,
        -0.48505995,  0.45497927]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.31677225,  0.3403609 ,  0.43394235, ..., -0.22031932,
        -0.19851643,  0.07987656],
       [ 0.23734477, -0.08880972,  0.29560354, ..., -0.29227307,
        -0.6075761 ,  0.0549405 ],
       [ 0.51728237,  0.92628396, -0.40312177, ...,  0.47099453,
         0.1400124 ,  0.5190122 ],
       ...,
       [-0.01423888, -0.00644734, -0.01985722, ...,  0.00387737,
         0.08140853, -0.04754239],
       [-0.20655577,  0.07879162,  0.16483389, ...,  0.03559271,
        -0.08346304,  0.02901335],
       [ 0.12661955, -0.14012276,  0.13914892, ...,  0.09200166,
        -0.01300973,  0.09209644]], dtype=float32), 5), (array([[ 0.6097177 ,  0.48289144,  0.107826  , ...,  0.14263372,
         0.43684664,  0.37251818],
       [-0.47600058, -0.32621023, -0.55021507, ..., -0.48766413,
         0.19021659, -0.25467217],
       [-0.26290026,  0.19371034, -0.3084416 , ..., -0.38468444,
        -0.24624074, -0.1248633 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.29716069, -0.17764345,  0.06396675, ..., -0.51036185,
        -0.16205388, -0.11298727],
       [ 0.11154262,  0.17699954, -0.55426383, ...,  0.36997363,
         0.10982917, -0.16837421],
       [-0.0491058 ,  0.13139851,  0.38043728, ..., -0.20505017,
         0.15700234,  0.5629593 ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 5.4628938e-01,  4.5117161e-01,  3.2670802e-01, ...,
         1.9686517e-01,  3.2789686e-01,  4.5343029e-01],
       [-6.4986098e-01, -2.4272519e-01, -7.6540470e-01, ...,
        -7.3495942e-01,  2.8457634e-02, -1.3791913e-01],
       [-7.1882963e-01,  6.7012483e-01, -6.4978844e-01, ...,
        -6.2161821e-01, -6.2733275e-01, -3.5520321e-01],
       ...,
       [-9.8777540e-02, -3.5368185e-02,  3.7035108e-02, ...,
         3.2906037e-02, -3.7386462e-02, -7.3537357e-02],
       [ 7.1388625e-02,  1.7618576e-01, -3.5727687e-02, ...,
        -1.8145926e-01, -8.1750348e-02,  1.6553156e-02],
       [-4.8265442e-02, -1.0864433e-01, -7.2953522e-02, ...,
         5.3536858e-02,  1.4538332e-04,  1.6074999e-01]], dtype=float32), 6), (array([[-0.60614747,  0.12892431, -0.3011826 , ...,  0.25248086,
        -0.52810246,  0.14257856],
       [-0.42474708, -0.37544054, -0.3886031 , ..., -0.35798463,
        -0.18877436,  0.3048291 ],
       [-0.17884058, -0.37839454,  0.3589297 , ...,  0.05497296,
        -0.06037642, -0.4278129 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.1893682 ,  0.22125317, -0.20827802, ..., -0.29234493,
        -0.1302274 ,  0.02801383],
       [ 0.1747711 , -0.0879383 , -0.395539  , ..., -0.38479805,
        -0.61469847,  0.00207329],
       [ 0.3819209 ,  0.49023125, -0.42264247, ...,  0.1528128 ,
         0.45578462,  0.4668125 ]], dtype=float32), array([[-5.28453410e-01,  1.38694681e-02, -2.60350943e-01, ...,
         2.34538317e-01, -4.43873584e-01,  1.47595644e-01],
       [-5.25614679e-01, -4.94065553e-01, -4.03498739e-01, ...,
        -4.45649236e-01, -1.77955553e-01,  3.10622215e-01],
       [ 1.01587474e-01, -8.57380509e-01,  8.03865731e-01, ...,
         2.06392854e-01, -1.75320432e-01, -7.59775221e-01],
       ...,
       [ 8.77973512e-02, -2.19333827e-01, -1.42306268e-01, ...,
        -1.03031479e-01,  6.18839522e-06,  1.56334475e-01],
       [-1.23811606e-02, -3.57912146e-02, -7.11395666e-02, ...,
         4.88635562e-02,  1.20033674e-01, -2.04370469e-02],
       [ 1.00751802e-01, -4.78806317e-01,  1.95426181e-01, ...,
        -5.01195967e-01, -3.37407261e-01,  3.57391506e-01]], dtype=float32), 7), (array([[ 0.49053288, -0.04683368, -0.0879433 , ...,  0.6166893 ,
        -0.5472508 ,  0.5924473 ],
       [-0.40197268,  0.21878959,  0.47748646, ..., -0.27519724,
         0.3854015 , -0.04976773],
       [ 0.24380569, -0.04194092, -0.22590604, ...,  0.35376453,
         0.2546404 , -0.20142618],
       ...,
       [-0.5142191 , -0.2877738 , -0.47166097, ...,  0.48306477,
         0.26082426, -0.4445646 ],
       [-0.25510445,  0.00508366, -0.5078671 , ..., -0.27604827,
        -0.08479042,  0.04850767],
       [-0.37874135,  0.49107817,  0.11259978, ...,  0.3188926 ,
         0.15944068,  0.0829725 ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.5134689 , -0.18948251, -0.05751067, ...,  0.48557195,
        -0.3173096 ,  0.372445  ],
       [-0.43809155, -0.08225048,  0.7466321 , ..., -0.5873075 ,
         0.7402181 , -0.09714872],
       [ 0.68586934,  0.1767921 ,  0.07150997, ...,  0.8427489 ,
         0.45624557, -0.32352042],
       ...,
       [ 0.02128473, -0.00579748,  0.12406835, ...,  0.08425785,
         0.21446604,  0.09736192],
       [ 0.04778935, -0.12865652,  0.00840133, ..., -0.00293668,
         0.06652898, -0.03904634],
       [ 0.02595548,  0.11789754, -0.02631662, ...,  0.03307972,
         0.24783   , -0.12637296]], dtype=float32), 8), (array([[-0.09508003,  0.5282958 ,  0.04243381, ..., -0.0648976 ,
        -0.56710106, -0.06858341],
       [-0.23444827, -0.17710732, -0.29838824, ..., -0.03992304,
        -0.51030684, -0.34101528],
       [ 0.00919831,  0.00875767, -0.09158213, ...,  0.26422626,
        -0.19114144,  0.2717857 ],
       ...,
       [-0.3377122 ,  0.49312168, -0.50667596, ..., -0.33557674,
        -0.3865259 ,  0.4990052 ],
       [ 0.17765625, -0.06699899,  0.29469523, ...,  0.612583  ,
         0.13147196, -0.27174017],
       [-0.56627136, -0.25801656, -0.28928643, ...,  0.18859185,
        -0.46310693,  0.23317206]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.22075664,  0.41444212, -0.4506032 , ..., -0.16359589,
        -0.569371  , -0.13674185],
       [-0.19642216, -0.36554584, -0.45241717, ..., -0.06579936,
        -0.656618  , -0.11742882],
       [-0.04687649,  0.10208729, -0.060711  , ...,  0.78385997,
        -0.17697819,  0.75614196],
       ...,
       [ 0.2150026 ,  0.15821525, -0.16107246, ..., -0.20459318,
        -0.20312549,  0.11470713],
       [ 0.06135871,  0.06140292, -0.11083869, ...,  0.14165913,
         0.05527819,  0.0520999 ],
       [ 0.13505958,  0.06166949, -0.11568853, ..., -0.04749477,
         0.02072733, -0.05888995]], dtype=float32), 9)]
```

`collect()` result is:

```
[(array([[ 0.18516347, -0.33975708, -0.46829244, ...,  0.498327  ,
        -0.1628269 ,  0.5171599 ],
       [ 0.24843855,  0.43924475,  0.43121427, ..., -0.3605212 ,
        -0.2543247 , -0.35761902],
       [ 0.03349265,  0.28567392, -0.3129074 , ...,  0.30228034,
         0.33539015,  0.28145155],
       ...,
       [ 0.39538023, -0.11668223,  0.23590142, ..., -0.39222914,
        -0.34792763,  0.43729994],
       [-0.37299404, -0.40583754, -0.41405225, ...,  0.3708834 ,
         0.6067088 ,  0.5815965 ],
       [-0.5297639 ,  0.09037948,  0.06255247, ...,  0.55813074,
         0.2599809 ,  0.2930913 ]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.05441456, -0.08513332, -0.47554415, ...,  0.46570715,
         0.11365455,  0.641596  ],
       [ 0.25915185,  0.6784206 ,  0.5428535 , ..., -0.3223893 ,
        -0.17784661, -0.3021973 ],
       [ 0.4007858 ,  0.48166505, -0.7551351 , ...,  0.5893394 ,
         0.5379706 ,  0.5853663 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.03785443, -0.02449032,  0.07482295, ...,  0.14570121,
         0.02578176,  0.11021709],
       [ 0.02157725,  0.20236807, -0.25889152, ..., -0.2123813 ,
         0.11124409,  0.05835798],
       [-0.2482176 ,  0.1100187 , -0.16054511, ...,  0.15483692,
        -0.01258843, -0.000899  ]], dtype=float32), 0), (array([[-0.06023056,  0.34326535,  0.01615176, ...,  0.50180113,
         0.35740197, -0.3607464 ],
       [-0.37374282, -0.05733229, -0.10494906, ...,  0.10067802,
        -0.30181995,  0.19373518],
       [-0.21093842, -0.35539758,  0.2722222 , ..., -0.13212524,
         0.15457118,  0.29343936],
       ...,
       [-0.3844776 ,  0.29577827,  0.23207994, ..., -0.2748728 ,
         0.05118364, -0.43278512],
       [ 0.18988602,  0.15946351, -0.37208527, ...,  0.18980268,
         0.26914784,  0.57002   ],
       [-0.19685334, -0.00215623, -0.50676346, ..., -0.25601804,
         0.43306062, -0.45977998]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.07212897,  0.37888303,  0.14216022, ...,  0.3568563 ,
         0.31809187, -0.30161127],
       [-0.14504915,  0.09403719, -0.24099208, ...,  0.1194509 ,
        -0.571604  ,  0.3073006 ],
       [-0.34506813, -0.5373435 ,  0.39612344, ..., -0.17277275,
        -0.15978633,  0.9480076 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.33411705,  0.3616483 , -0.00284358, ..., -0.1570069 ,
        -0.10693   ,  0.11339971],
       [ 0.03463184,  0.02923653, -0.07571009, ..., -0.01076985,
        -0.24661644,  0.07400434],
       [ 0.03500444,  0.02041529,  0.11345199, ..., -0.21085429,
        -0.11910766, -0.16162656]], dtype=float32), 1), (array([[ 0.40148696,  0.44860718, -0.13891219, ...,  0.38478658,
         0.0354558 ,  0.5507143 ],
       [ 0.35727167,  0.33523828, -0.40109852, ..., -0.12698223,
        -0.48993534,  0.4485451 ],
       [-0.37534824, -0.07898732, -0.28266475, ...,  0.0923453 ,
         0.20398574,  0.46967202],
       ...,
       [-0.31968838,  0.47479796, -0.49929148, ..., -0.23865293,
        -0.24262336, -0.06511039],
       [ 0.2098573 , -0.5782443 ,  0.0044039 , ..., -0.13356705,
        -0.5997722 ,  0.24789433],
       [ 0.18989192, -0.41790476, -0.5493083 , ..., -0.04386537,
         0.14099114, -0.3851897 ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.35465854,  0.5298055 ,  0.09639163, ...,  0.42402148,
         0.1006598 ,  0.42896628],
       [ 0.49630994,  0.53968257, -0.45613742, ...,  0.11758496,
        -0.82799774,  0.47129843],
       [-0.11091773, -0.126068  , -0.94792765, ..., -0.39254257,
         0.49629924,  0.90804875],
       ...,
       [ 0.09986763,  0.18694244,  0.04551417, ..., -0.00185746,
         0.04787954,  0.14079888],
       [ 0.01976901,  0.01671817,  0.02434383, ..., -0.05640491,
         0.03537085, -0.08094196],
       [-0.12894829,  0.15826981, -0.09516723, ..., -0.11121278,
        -0.17831786, -0.00805143]], dtype=float32), 2), (array([[-0.16927287, -0.3801918 , -0.32327962, ..., -0.51245123,
         0.41986853,  0.18242987],
       [-0.41638187, -0.06312063, -0.40284333, ...,  0.26918623,
        -0.4305522 , -0.4801858 ],
       [ 0.00497885, -0.22712015, -0.35257223, ...,  0.02938372,
         0.32673585,  0.176891  ],
       ...,
       [ 0.22629777,  0.39141867,  0.3272797 , ..., -0.45520803,
         0.17408061, -0.27852598],
       [-0.24445221, -0.35762975, -0.39768136, ...,  0.26196685,
         0.17221238,  0.22423406],
       [ 0.38731757, -0.45889175,  0.3848555 , ...,  0.469341  ,
         0.2884723 ,  0.4584588 ]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.38282454, -0.33555806, -0.38107285, ..., -0.4294134 ,
         0.40941086,  0.19802842],
       [-0.5812499 , -0.08969598, -0.5220119 , ...,  0.35569692,
        -0.436198  , -0.78949076],
       [-0.6598932 , -0.61103916, -0.8173852 , ...,  0.39758506,
         0.77731544,  0.38008815],
       ...,
       [ 0.16403008, -0.06079637, -0.02834259, ..., -0.10361861,
         0.10504336,  0.21878755],
       [-0.04492131, -0.17708012, -0.2025333 , ...,  0.17902693,
        -0.15750957, -0.23726523],
       [-0.07494884, -0.06165536, -0.10450385, ...,  0.17355536,
         0.01258762, -0.05638846]], dtype=float32), 3), (array([[ 0.00608851, -0.5132972 , -0.36956814, ..., -0.5321781 ,
        -0.26002124,  0.18518737],
       [-0.21294856, -0.30260456,  0.11435414, ..., -0.52438897,
        -0.46490332, -0.43702644],
       [ 0.32582685, -0.25917143, -0.34966806, ..., -0.29239386,
        -0.09908075,  0.32888958],
       ...,
       [-0.25709772,  0.32678795,  0.00447032, ..., -0.04280795,
         0.01051257,  0.36575   ],
       [-0.07194624, -0.245111  ,  0.5667958 , ...,  0.41409835,
        -0.5799336 , -0.4858021 ],
       [-0.11811656,  0.52633476,  0.40527648, ...,  0.40293694,
        -0.4926284 , -0.14098077]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.11553568, -0.3299477 , -0.50079507, ..., -0.44186658,
         0.01149882,  0.01778618],
       [-0.3005174 , -0.26895422,  0.08186761, ..., -0.7348857 ,
        -0.5810445 , -0.53310806],
       [ 0.5055336 , -0.35796392, -0.90873146, ..., -0.78193223,
        -0.04517283,  0.7075767 ],
       ...,
       [-0.02022595,  0.01297146, -0.02664614, ...,  0.10258275,
        -0.06243805, -0.07688553],
       [-0.24571168,  0.18370496,  0.03886681, ..., -0.03063186,
        -0.04676892, -0.10450852],
       [ 0.03074093, -0.045911  ,  0.07248624, ..., -0.05876327,
         0.06366935, -0.01161662]], dtype=float32), 4), (array([[-0.28593373,  0.13395616,  0.48233178, ...,  0.508933  ,
        -0.19197209,  0.3298264 ],
       [-0.04904724,  0.34900156,  0.32834592, ..., -0.42706388,
        -0.39813402,  0.14217453],
       [ 0.13526852,  0.3745679 ,  0.12265893, ...,  0.30098978,
         0.15158501,  0.2164896 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.21077481,  0.31915814, -0.32008937, ..., -0.48824465,
         0.15033281, -0.55469203],
       [-0.33247608, -0.05625575,  0.43155706, ...,  0.34942424,
         0.04699863,  0.17167164],
       [-0.32446697,  0.3883351 , -0.18434255, ..., -0.481489  ,
         0.38606554, -0.31928998]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.21347475,  0.1707647 ,  0.40377334, ...,  0.21519852,
        -0.2119801 ,  0.19800745],
       [ 0.11622372,  0.4918646 ,  0.4055998 , ..., -0.65552425,
        -0.5142339 ,  0.01027841],
       [ 0.5708596 ,  0.58031136,  0.5869403 , ...,  0.7259039 ,
         0.10178877,  0.09589735],
       ...,
       [-0.04035015,  0.08506791,  0.00343785, ...,  0.06102315,
         0.07513183, -0.05011833],
       [ 0.15481526,  0.14573523, -0.04516461, ..., -0.14253813,
        -0.0463484 , -0.2259047 ],
       [ 0.22652309,  0.2351952 , -0.03388155, ..., -0.04040325,
        -0.17493977, -0.28690276]], dtype=float32), 5), (array([[ 0.01241684,  0.3848157 , -0.39109015, ...,  0.5478949 ,
        -0.56430525,  0.6666779 ],
       [ 0.14730261, -0.01858082, -0.3315102 , ...,  0.2657176 ,
        -0.33017242,  0.21192974],
       [ 0.33523917, -0.18178591, -0.3066008 , ...,  0.20106438,
        -0.22945583, -0.03762559],
       ...,
       [-0.2540486 ,  0.18161409, -0.18843989, ..., -0.2343464 ,
        -0.09964091, -0.06174641],
       [-0.04365243,  0.5485354 ,  0.20301312, ...,  0.46485335,
        -0.5898763 , -0.32282397],
       [-0.48032835, -0.44875026,  0.27545917, ..., -0.38980302,
        -0.42448705, -0.28787732]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.12385425,  0.34021133, -0.5947283 , ...,  0.5262172 ,
        -0.50784826,  0.6099582 ],
       [ 0.36343968, -0.00910554, -0.4031666 , ...,  0.29984346,
        -0.51017505,  0.19207458],
       [ 0.7371366 , -0.05033325, -0.65316683, ...,  0.6836462 ,
        -0.82514614,  0.05400744],
       ...,
       [ 0.00850144,  0.14323875, -0.17175199, ...,  0.02427784,
         0.08420605,  0.08254603],
       [-0.05369973,  0.1430688 , -0.18583198, ...,  0.22647178,
        -0.23855914,  0.11469093],
       [-0.16125312,  0.00549565, -0.1524472 , ...,  0.02182539,
        -0.07359254,  0.13050811]], dtype=float32), 6), (array([[-0.04644716,  0.05705595, -0.24267559, ..., -0.21403529,
        -0.06703684,  0.41887376],
       [-0.29370484, -0.39780775, -0.3568661 , ..., -0.09881599,
         0.07795003,  0.38119403],
       [-0.3645612 ,  0.10963462, -0.347853  , ..., -0.27757406,
        -0.27060333,  0.3227043 ],
       ...,
       [ 0.29615575, -0.4612898 ,  0.05339388, ..., -0.08740558,
        -0.25723857, -0.49486127],
       [ 0.05623814,  0.4080824 , -0.24716274, ..., -0.09058192,
         0.1756261 , -0.3089906 ],
       [-0.5414306 ,  0.4408762 ,  0.42941254, ...,  0.15542302,
         0.5396825 , -0.2709453 ]], dtype=float32), array([[-3.42568368e-01,  1.64543867e-01,  1.99411588e-04, ...,
        -2.34075099e-01,  4.41714190e-02,  3.03957969e-01],
       [-4.59636778e-01, -4.12208438e-01, -4.32887614e-01, ...,
        -5.51471636e-02,  2.10178539e-01,  5.81714928e-01],
       [-1.12530768e+00,  6.36167228e-01, -6.05338633e-01, ...,
        -5.48392713e-01, -2.09195793e-01,  1.01132858e+00],
       ...,
       [-1.30258754e-01, -4.16335762e-02,  1.45700663e-01, ...,
        -3.17536071e-02,  3.02174967e-02,  1.10822864e-01],
       [-1.39803439e-01,  3.05877943e-02,  1.05636232e-01, ...,
         1.10526226e-01,  6.08176775e-02, -5.73274679e-02],
       [-2.55209617e-02,  1.39828652e-01, -5.54599836e-02, ...,
         1.40946835e-01,  1.95314527e-01, -7.23765837e-03]], dtype=float32), 7), (array([[-0.07237607, -0.06369619, -0.57799906, ..., -0.3011678 ,
        -0.3869047 , -0.5708126 ],
       [-0.00725966, -0.04352329, -0.14471681, ..., -0.47405225,
        -0.11870398,  0.44799381],
       [ 0.36965963,  0.19295754, -0.25880384, ..., -0.27418908,
        -0.2637073 , -0.25275636],
       ...,
       [ 0.06180732,  0.10883695, -0.20686714, ..., -0.4045689 ,
        -0.10775824, -0.00597983],
       [ 0.17705184,  0.2853461 ,  0.38804924, ...,  0.00480051,
         0.23195331,  0.5900061 ],
       [ 0.33405438, -0.05846346, -0.49157378, ...,  0.13280089,
         0.4277615 , -0.43489072]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.02955375,  0.03905029, -0.5314531 , ..., -0.3317717 ,
        -0.32801694, -0.5832374 ],
       [-0.15554425,  0.01338848, -0.30303237, ..., -0.5683995 ,
         0.07281558,  0.39870417],
       [ 0.57431275,  0.48248613, -0.36046496, ..., -0.740754  ,
        -0.4101879 , -0.46861094],
       ...,
       [-0.05291473, -0.00626671, -0.16552408, ..., -0.21676618,
         0.00198667,  0.15837853],
       [-0.20605578,  0.02732588,  0.05644984, ..., -0.14183098,
         0.11027621,  0.00878341],
       [ 0.01149986,  0.02788752, -0.07346534, ...,  0.02313588,
         0.0365326 ,  0.0427165 ]], dtype=float32), 8), (array([[ 0.32586667,  0.6187046 ,  0.3162743 , ...,  0.42238498,
        -0.08919488, -0.23198491],
       [ 0.1516603 ,  0.04449864,  0.10896807, ..., -0.49212578,
         0.14955266, -0.04248938],
       [-0.23296818, -0.16775374,  0.41552317, ..., -0.27849862,
         0.08736038,  0.36777073],
       ...,
       [ 0.17306753,  0.4053642 , -0.063707  , ...,  0.09530412,
        -0.46045092,  0.42887986],
       [-0.63025045,  0.3146556 ,  0.148895  , ...,  0.48645812,
         0.27349007, -0.0574788 ],
       [-0.00731906, -0.03560491, -0.3711313 , ...,  0.2597622 ,
         0.44751585,  0.30753264]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.48764184,  0.54429394,  0.461604  , ...,  0.5304342 ,
         0.20013283, -0.23899378],
       [ 0.15820505, -0.131124  , -0.02082682, ..., -0.58288604,
         0.04917484, -0.06569459],
       [-0.74465793, -0.29858342,  1.2702694 , ..., -0.80466145,
         0.45967343,  0.913658  ],
       ...,
       [-0.02027037, -0.06839398, -0.14130257, ..., -0.14568064,
        -0.02432712,  0.02081295],
       [-0.03228899, -0.05201127,  0.1773543 , ...,  0.05981961,
        -0.13131005,  0.00199337],
       [-0.14305267,  0.02065172,  0.01255422, ...,  0.02369817,
         0.0101981 ,  0.13320476]], dtype=float32), 9)]
```

Any idea about what this weird behaviour? Maybe something related to byte order in Numpy ndarray's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. I forgot about Spark lazy evaluation (`map()` is a transformation, not an action as `take()` and `collect()` are; tranformations are not actually evaluated until an action is called).

This, combined with the fact **my mapping function seems to be not idempotent** (i.e. it does not return the same value upon executions) leads to following behaviour: calling `take(10)` actually evaluates the `map()` for a first time (returning a value), and calling `collect()` actually evaluates the `map()` for a second time (and returning a totally different value).